# R for loop or apply on data table columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, multiple-columns

Trying to do some operation on each column in a data frame. Not sure to use `apply` or `for` (not sure how to ignore the first column in `apply`).

**Question 1:**

To simply print each name twice I figured out:

`for (i in names(dt)){if(str_length(i) < 3) {print(i);print(i)}}`

The first column's name is the only one with a string length > 3 which is why I used that.

I tried using:

```
for (i in dt$i){if(str_length(names(i)) < 3) {print(i);print(i)}}
for (i in dt$i){if(str_length(names(dt)) < 3) {print(i);print(i)}}
```

To simply print each column twice, but it just created an empty value.

**Question 2:**

What I'd actually to do instead of print twice; is order each column: `order(-i)`??

Then create a subset: `head(i, n=500)`??

Not sure if this is extra step or an extension of the above step. Then define that as a data.frame; `dt(i) < data.frame(head(i, n=500))`??

Then save that table: `write.csv(dt(i), "newfolder/i.csv", row.names = FALSE)` - I think that will just constantly overwrite one file called i.csv, not sure how I'd name the file based on i.

Maybe `apply` is a better approach, I'm not sure.

I simplest approach (such that i understand what's going on) would be  appreciated. I only have 40 columns, each with 50,000 rows, so it shouldn't be that slow.

**EDIT**

Trying to be more clear I will add an example:

```
Name  Math Science PE
David  90    70    25
Tom    100   60    40
John   30    40    100
```

I would want to end with 3 csv's with the first looking like:

```
Name Math
Tom  100
David 90
```

In the above case n=2 for head. Also the csv could have the other columns, but they are not required.

Comment: `not sure how I'd name the file based on i.` - use `paste0("myFile", i, ".csv")`

Comment: Your post is not very clear and maybe closed as too broad. Please add input data and expected output. `apply` is just a prettified version of `for loop`, so it is up to you which one to use.

Comment: Was my edit enough info?

Comment: Thank you for edit, is Name a rowname or a column?

Comment: It is a column already, hence why in my example at the start I used str_length for names() as that is the only column with a name more than 2 letters - the data table comes from a csv, I suppose I could have defined the column as names, not sure if thats better practice or not.

Comment: There are no rownames, or they are simply 2-50000. Also i'm hoping for an answer using the for loop. Maybe lapply will be used within the loop. For each column Id like to sort the column, subset it, save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your dummy data, we can loop through "subject" columns 2:n, then sort, and write out top 2 results:

```
# dummy data
df <- read.table(text="Name  Math Science PE
David  90    70    25
Tom    100   60    40
John   30    40    100", header = TRUE)


# loop and write csv for top 2 scores
lapply(colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)], function(i){
  res <- df[, c("Name", i)]
  res <- res[order(res[, i], decreasing = TRUE),]
  write.csv(head(res, 2), file = paste0(i, ".csv"))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (using `mtcars` as an example):

```
mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars, sort)
head(mtcars)
```

Here, you sort each column from smallest to largest. Note that each individual row is not useful anymore, since it is not representing a particular unit. You do get your desired output though. Then you can just use `head()` to get your desired number of entries.

To see what happens:

First, how the original data look:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Now let's sort each column:

```
> mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars, sort)
```

What the output looks like:

```
> head(mtcars, 5)
                   mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         10.4   4 71.1 52 2.76 1.513 14.50  0  0    3    1
Mazda RX4 Wag     10.4   4 75.7 62 2.76 1.615 14.60  0  0    3    1
Datsun 710        13.3   4 78.7 65 2.93 1.835 15.41  0  0    3    1
Hornet 4 Drive    14.3   4 79.0 66 3.00 1.935 15.50  0  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 14.7   4 95.1 66 3.07 2.140 15.84  0  0    3    1
```

You also see that the rownames are not informative anymore. Please make sure that this is what you want. To get the smallest 500 rows of your new dataframe for saving, just use regular subsetting, such as `df[1:500,]`.

**To keep the names**, we can generate a list of dataframes instead:

```
newdat <- lapply(mtcars, function(x){
  dat <- data.frame(ind = rownames(mtcars), out = x)
  dat <- dat[order(dat$out),]
})
```

Here, the output will be a list with the old rownames (called `ind`) and the ordered column called `out`. It is a named list, where each list element corresponds to the name of the original column. Note that you can use the `list` structure further, such as in `lapply(newdat, head)`.

Comment: I want the row name to change when each column is sorted, also would I use apply within a for loop then? The first column is a load of variable and each other column represents a different sector. For each sector im trying to order the variables and save the top variables, such that after this I will write another loop to plot each sector. hope that makes sense

Comment: @OliPaul add rownames as a new column, then sort. `mtcars$myNames <- rownames(mtcars)`, then do the sorting.

Comment: They already are, but when sorting in the loop, the names are not values and I wouldn't want them sorted

Comment: The names are a column, I just don't wish that column to be a part of the loop where I am sorting and saving multiple csv's

Comment: Then just replace `rownames(mtcars)` with the name of your column containing the names. Similarly, you need to replace `mtcars` with the name of your dataset. In any case, if you want to keep the names, they need to be sorted as well, and the solution above shows you how to do it.